# Knife isn't using Knife.rb

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Chef: 14.1.12 Windows 10
Going through the tutorial [here](https://learn.chef.io/modules/manage-a-node-chef-server/ubuntu/bring-your-own-system/set-up-your-chef-server#/) I have my knife.rb at ~/learn-chef/.chef/knife.rb (C:\users\wdavis\learn-chef.chef\knife.rb)

I run the ssl fetch
`knife ssl fetch`

```
Results:
    INFO: Using configuration from C:/Users/wdavis/learn-chef/.chef/knife.rb
    WARNING: Certificates from localhost will be fetched and placed in your trusted_cert
    directory (c:\users\wdavis\learn-chef\.chef\trusted_certs).

    Knife has no means to verify these are the correct certificates. You should
    verify the authenticity of these certificates after downloading.

    ERROR: Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. - SSL_connect
```

Here is my knife.rb:

```
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                 :info
log_location              STDOUT
node_name                 "chefadmin"
client_key                "#{current_dir}/chefadmin.pem"
chef_server_url           "https://synchef.url.com/organizations/syn"
cookbook_path             ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks/"]
```

However, if I run:
`knife ssl fetch https://synchef.url.com`

It works fine - so why isn't it working when just using the knife.rb?

I should also add I'm seeing similar issues when trying to upload cookbooks. It says it's using my knife.rb and the cookbooks are obviously there but it claims it cannot find them.

So it seems to me maybe it isn't really using the knife.rb it should?

and here is another example:

```
knife ssl check -V
INFO: Using configuration from C:/Users/wdavis/learn-chef/.chef/knife.rb
Connecting to host localhost:443
ERROR: Errno::ECONNRESET: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. - SSL_connect
```

Why is it trying to connect to localhost:443? That isn't what is configured in my knife.rb

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the original file in VS Code - which saved the file as UTF-16 LE. I noticed that in the starter kit I downloaded the file was UTF-8. I resaved my file in UTF-8 and the command worked fine. It seems that the version of ruby shipped with ChefDk doesnt like UTF-16LE?